# F2PY modules in parallel

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have an existing Fortran module that I want to run in parallel. For example, I want 8 instances of the module, each with its own variable scope, all working at once. Is that possible with f2py? From the documentation, it seems that when you import a module, you only have access to a single copy of the Fortran object.

I'm newish to Python and very new to Fortran, so let me know if this approach is even worth investigating.

Comment: Possibly, using some multi-processing library in Python and load a Fortran module from each process?

Comment: Yes for sure. You import the F2PY-created library normally. You can use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` to run multiple instances of anything including the F2PY functions. No need to import from different processes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run your imported functions from the f2py-object like any other function in parallel, for example using `concurrent.futures`. For example, it can look like this on the python side:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import f2py_module as fm
# Or if a fortran module "my_module" is wrapped, do
from f2py_module import my_module as fm

print (fm.__doc__) # to see functions definitions, comment out

def task(arg):
    """This wrapper is not needed, but usually convenient to define
    redundant arguments or transforming the result somehow"""
    res = fm.calculate(arg) # calculate is a Fortran subroutine
    return res 

PEX = cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) # 4 threads here

args = [1,2,3,4,5] 

processes = [PEX.submit(task,arg) for arg in args]
res = [pr.result() for pr in processes]

for re in res:
    print(re)
```

Comment: Depending on what the OP means by "each with its own variable scope", this approach may not work as intended. Consider the output of the following my_module.f90: `module my_module;
  implicit none;
  integer :: mod_num = 0;
contains;
  subroutine calculate(num, res);
    integer, intent(in)   :: num;
    integer, intent(out)  :: res;
    mod_num = mod_num + num;
    res = mod_num;
  end subroutine calculate;
end module my_module`

Comment: I agree, good point. If the execution changes the state of the Fortran module this will give unexpected results. So one needs to make sure to not do that. Considering how python imports work, it might be hard to sandbox the module for each process.

Comment: However wouldn't this be the case for ANY python function, from any module? They "can't" be reimported and if they change the state of the module (maybe using `global`) they would give unexpected behavior. Possibly deleting them from the global index and then importing would work in both cases.

Comment: And I agree with what you say, just think this could be a useful clarification to add to the answer, considering how I understood the question being asked by the OP.